# Unable to upgrade automatically krb5 package on latest nginx docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, prisma

I am using the image nginx:latest on my docker file and not upgraded automatically on the security patch provided by debian source. Is there any way to update it on my docker image? Please find the below link for reference.

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/krb5

```
CVE-2021-36222 | 7.50 | krb5    | 1.17-3+deb10u1 | fixed in 1.17-3+deb10u2
```

Could you please help me on resolving this issue?